# Html.CheckBoxFor somehow save state through two request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Actually i'm developing new asp.net mvc app in most like qustionare. But while developing i came across an issue. I created action method which renders questions one by one depending on passed questionId. So when i try to render next question, my Html.CheckBoxFor somehow remember state of previous question and just left the same state independently from real value.
Does anybody experienced such error?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code so that someone can take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Post action, try clearing the model and then using ModelState.Clear() before passing it to the view again.

Validation information and model bindings are kept when posting back from an [HTTPPost] action unless you clear the model's state. I think there is an assumption in MVC you would only post back to show validation messages and allow changes.  If that's not the case then use ModelState.Clear() and reset your values. see link below...

[Why you need ModelState.Clear](https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modelstate-clear-is-required-to-display-back-your-model-object)

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. But why it occured?

Comment: There's a lot of information kept for posting back from a Post Action. particularly for validation but it also keeps the Model bindings.  I guess they assume you would only re-post in order to show validation errors.  so ModelState.Clear() must be called to show new information in the model.  You can also clear specific attributes of the model but I don't have the code for that. Please mark as right if it worked for you

Comment: Don't know why I got a -1 for answering the question correctly :(

Comment: Can you mark as correct please

Comment: It has been completed